# Best way to store date from CSV file into SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, date, datetime

Hey currently working on converting csv file into SQL and trying to figure out the best approach to storing the date column from my sql file. I need to be able to do queries to get a selection of records within a certain date like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE DateTime >= '12/04/2011 12:00:00 AM' AND DateTime <= '25/05/2011 3:53:04 AM'
```

The data from my CSV for each date is stored as 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm' what is the best approach for converting this data and inserting it into a column in sql. Do I set the column as a string column or a DateTime column to be able to query based on the date? Do I just use the convert() function when entering the data into the table?

I can't seem to figure out the best practice and approach as there is a lot of conflicting answers out there. Any quick example would be sooo helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dates belong in DATETIME columns. You can't do anything useful with them otherwise. You can't sort them properly, query them properly, or do anything else with them if they're not DATETIME values. There's a DATETIME datatype for a reason. Test this yourself - create a table with a character column, put a few dozen rows in using your format, and try to do date-based queries against them (rows between dates that cross a year boundary, for example).

Comment: @KenWhite it looks like my format doesn't work in datetime... when I insert for example '10/11/1998 20:30' it doesn't through an error but shows up as a record with value 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Is the only answer preprocessing the value into the correct format?

Comment: That value is a string, which needs to be converted to a DATETIME. It's absolutely necessary to do so if you're going to use the data after importing it, as I mentioned previously. It looks like you've got an answer that explains how to handle it below from @Chris.

Comment: @KenWhite Sounds good, I'll just write a quick script to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to import your CSV data into SQL once then I would do some manipulation of the date format first.

You want to get the dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. After you've done this then make the column in your database a `DATETIME`

Once you've done this then you'll be able to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE DateColumnName >= '2011-04-12 12:00:00' AND DateColumnName <= '2011-05-25 03:53:04'
```